How to handle zoom event in lightningChart js
I am using lightningChart js 5.2.0 in my angular application. I want to get maximum and minimum value of x axis when I zoom in or out on the chart using mouse wheel. So that I can use setFormattingFunction to format the x axis value.
I am stuck in this problem for a long time and I haven't gotten anywhere yet. So if there is someone who can help me solving this issue that would be of great help. Thanks

Could you please share the code?
